# Why is jQuery not Detecting Dynamically Added Classes on Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Noob question I apologize, but I have been struggling with this for way too long

```
jQuery(".mutiple_form_navigation_link > div" ).on( "click", function() {
        jQuery("#shipping_customer_details .validate-required").each(function(){
            console.log(jQuery(this));
                if (jQuery(this).hasClass('wooccommerce-invalid')) {
                    alert('invalid shipping');
                }
        });
```

Looking at the raw html when clicking

```
<p class="form-row form-row-last validate-required validate-Select woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field showErrors" id="shipping_last_name_field" data-priority="">
```

It has the class `woocommerce_invalid`

Looking at the `console.log` in my jquery it says

```
p#shipping_last_name_field.form-row.form-row-last.validate-required.validate-Select.woocommerce-invalid.woocommerce-invalid-required-field.showErrors
```

Showing `woocommerce-invalid` is a class...
yet `hasClass` is not triggering because apparently `woocommerce-invalid` was not there on DOM load, but rather after input validations?

How do I modify my `on("click")` jQuery to detect the class in the DOM...?

Comment: Because getting elements that match a selector and then doing something with them is a thing that happens immediately.

Comment: Just to expand on the above comment - which is certainly the correct answer: On the very first line of your code snippet there, what you're doing is looking for an element and attaching an event. If that element doesn't exist when the code runs - it won't work.

What you can do instead is write your listener like this:
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.mutiple_form_navigation_link > div' ...

This way - you're attaching the event to document click and THEN checking what has been clicked - so it will fire for dynamically created elements.

Comment: @JBoss that's actually very easy.  Thank you for dumbing it down for me :)